# Stop error: Chromedriver only supports chrome version xx (c#, Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, server, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

Guys i have a webcrawler working on server and works based on its schedule. every 2-3 days i see this error because of mismatching versions of chrome and driver.

> Chromedriver only supports chrome version xx (c#, Selenium)

It always causes my program to stop on server. How can I **somehow** stop updating versions?

Comment: What kind of _server_ do you use? Maybe the Chrome is updated on that machine and this is the reason for version mismatch?

Comment: @Jonah A normall windows 10 server. Yeah it's because of updating main chrome browser i think. Don't know how to stop it